Is there a correct answer to "How should foreign names be pronounced in English"?
There are some names that are pronounced very differently in English Language media around the world.  One famous example is Vincent van Gogh the artist, another that is in a lot of media at the moment is Houthi, the family that largely control Yemen.
Is there actually a correct answer to how to pronounce foreign names when speaking English?  Is it correct to say that any pronunciation that does match that of the person or group being referred to is "wrong"?  Is it correct to say the the right pronunciation of a name varies with the speakers dialect?  Is there a universal "right" way to say foreign names in English that is different from the native pronunciation?
This question asks a similar but more focused question.  This answer to that question would be valid to this one, but it has no votes and does not seem to match the way the world works so I think asking the specific question has value.  This question approaches the question from a practical public speaking point of view, I am more interested from a theoretical and/or international media point of view.

No, I don't think there is.

There's no rule, and nobody to impose a preferred pronunciation. Some organizations like the British Broadcasting Corporation have internal rules, but none is universally applicable. (And if you think English pronunciation of foreign words is bad, look at how the Japanese do it.)

This becomes a question of etiquette (defer to the name owner's pronunciation) rather than a matter of standard English practice. In a famous sketch, Monty Python took someone to task for not pronouncing 'Raymond Luxury Yacht' 'Raymond Throat-Warbler Mangrove'.

Considering that native English words are "pronounced very differently in English Language media around the world" it's not so surprising that the same is true of some foreign names.

@phoog English names of political leaders are not pronounced very differently in English Language media around the world.  If for example all Chinese media pronounced Biden as Brandon that would be a political issue.  Why the English medias pronunciation of Houthi is not seems relevant.

Anglicizing   foreign names has been an English practice for hundreds of years. For example Don Quickset (pronunciation, I mean) ; Jakes.

I assume that the question concerns the pronunciation by native speakers of language L of the names of native speakers of another language Q:  should they pronounce it according to the phonetic rules of L-ish or of Q-ish?  The British (or at least its upper classes) are/were notorious for using their unmodified native accents.  But the question is one of simple courtesy rather than correct phonetics.  It is not a matter of language usage, though it is important.  Britain and the USA have significant numbers of citizens and residents whose names should not be considered "foreign".

Some people seem to deal with this matter differently depending on whether the name is a name of a living person (particularly a person they are interacting with directly), a name of a historical personage, a geographical name, or a common noun. (It should be noted that this question is specifically about names, while the other one is about foreign words more generally.) These differences may have more to do with what they perceive as the requirements of etiquette than with any rule of the language proper.

@EdwinAshworth What happens if you’re ‘dialectically incapable’ of pronouncing somebody’s name the same way they themselves do? Notice how my linked examples are proper names that aren’t especially foreign per se, just ones whose native pronunciations vary a lot depending on the region and dialect its owner calls their own. We can’t even be bothered to say Mount Everest the way Sir George Everest [ˈiːvɹɨst] did his own!

Indeed. But OP's 'should' implies deontic modality, and obviously it wouldn't be ethical to expect people to do the impossible, so the dialectically incapable should be viewed as a special set and the argument confined to the complement set.

There is no single correct answer to how to pronounce non-English-language names when speaking English. A sensible (and polite) criterion is to hew as close as possible to the referent’s own pronunciation, but that can prove a high bar if the the referent’s own pronunciation includes sounds unused in English, unfamiliar to the speaker, and sometimes even unnoticed by anglophone ears.
And then there is the challenge of what to do about names from the many tonal languages. As one example, in Mandarin, tone distinguishes between otherwise similar-sounding words in much the same way as, say, vowels do. So just as English speakers hear Jan, Jane, Jen, and John as four utterly different names, a Mandarin speaker named 明 (Míng, like the dynasty, and meaning bright, clear, or intelligent) might be perfectly pleased with how his name is spoken in

Who gave you the book? Was it Ming?

but he might feel his name to have been mistaken for 命, (mìng, meaning life, or fate or destiny) if spoken in

I already told you that Sally didn’t water the plants. It was Ming.

What’s going on in that example is that in English, a key way to make a sentence a question is to use a rising pitch when speaking the final syllable, and a way one emphasizes a word is to use an initially high and then falling pitch. These pitch patterns are essentially identical to the so-called second and fourth tones in Mandarin. And in Mandarin, the tones don’t change a word’s role in an utterance, they change which word it is. It’s roughly analogous to the difference between

At breakfast, I had toast with Jim

and

At breakfast, I had toast with jam.


Yes, but it is limited.
The correct way to pronounce any personal name is the way in which the owner pronounces it.
If you do not know the pronunciation of the name, then you should ask or do some research.
Some non-English names do contain sounds (or combinations of sounds) that are difficult for people who do not speak that language, and attempts at pronunciation may be inaccurate.
Written personal names are difficult subject: they are usually written in the language of the owner and give no clue as to how they might be correctly pronounced, e.g.Saoirse and Niamh (Irish) are pronounced “Ser-sha,” and "Neev or nee-iv" respectively.
Some English surnames, "Featherstonehaugh" "Mainwaring" are deceptive - they are pronounced "fan'shor" and "mannering" respectively.
Further complications arise when the name is in a non-Roman alphabet. Various letters of the foreign alphabet may have sounds that can be transliterated in several ways - and the owner may have chosen an obscure one.
In this latter case there are usually official conventions on the transliteration (particularly in the matter of passports) and hence the pronunciation becomes the closest approximation in that recipient language. However these conventions are not well known, easy to find, or commonly used.

"The correct way to pronounce any personal name is the way in which the owner pronounces it": this is too simplistic to be correct.  In any event, it doesn't cover the Van Gogh case, where the problem is that different English speakers adapt the non-English phonemes differently.

One caveat — if a name contains sounds that are not pronounceable in English, it's perfectly acceptable to approximate them with the closet English sounds. For example, Bach is frequently pronounced [bɑːk] when it should really be pronounced [bɑχ], and Dvožak is pronounced [dɪˈvɔrʒɑːk] or  [ˈdvɔrʒɑːk] when it should really be pronounced [ˈdvor̝ɑːk]. I once spent around five minutes with a Czech trying to figure out the difference between rzh and the Czech consonant ž. I didn't even learn how to tell the sounds apart, let alone reproduce ž.

@Peter Closet English sounds? Singing in the washroom?

@PeterShor, I agree with the sentiment, but have some reservations about "perfectly".  Some people still might not want to accept it, even though they're unlikely to get any better offers.

@DougWarren: Well ... unless you're prepared to make English speakers spend half an hour understanding the difference between Dvožak and Dvorzhak, this is as good as you're going to get. And furthermore, I find people who try to pronounce all Spanish (or French) words with an authentic Spanish (or French) accent to be unbearably pretentious (native speakers of these languages excepted).

@phoog "The correct way to pronounce any personal name is the way in which the owner pronounces it": this is too simplistic to be correct." You are wrong (except for the case in which the owner of the name has a marked speech impediment.) "In any event, it doesn't cover the Van Gogh case, where the problem is that different English speakers adapt the non-English phonemes differently." If you had read my answer, you would have noted that I have covered this.

@Greybeard do you pronounce "Parker" differently when speaking of Nathaniel Parker and Sarah Jessica Parker?  I doubt it.  I read the part about "sounds that are difficult for people who do not speak that language, and attempts at pronunciation may be inaccurate."  The aspect of the Van Gogh case that this doesn't address is the fact that different portions of the English language community have adopted different (so-called) inaccurate pronunciations of the name as their standard naturalized pronunciation.  (This is also the case with many French words, if not most, including many names).

How exactly is this answer supposed to be applied to, say, Aristotle?

Perhaps the overriding principle here should be that the worries about how to pronounce something should never be allowed to get in the way of actual communication. If every time an English speaker tries to say something about Dvožak, somebody interrupts with 'No, no, it's not pronounced like that. Listen, the correct way to pronounce ž is . . .', it will be difficult for English speakers to have relaxed, spontaneous conversations about Dvožak.

@phoog "The aspect of the Van Gogh case that this doesn't address" It does.

@Greybeard do you want to explain how you suppose it addresses it?  There's nothing in the answer that comes even close to the issue of pluricentrism.

This isn’t limited to “foreign” names. Suppose someone tells you their name is Colin Carlin or Catherine Ashton or Basil O’Rourke or Anna Cohrs, but they pronounce the vowels and R’s in their names completely and utterly differently from how you yourself say those vowels and R’s in your own dialect. Now what  are you “supposed” to do? Shouldn’t you out of respect use ᴛʜᴇɪʀ pronunciations of ᴛʜᴇɪʀ names for them–even though these sound-combos essentially don’t exist in your own speech and dialect? Have you ever tried that? It’s remarkably difficult, if not impossible, to maintain.

@phoog There's nothing in the answer .... Are you arguing for the sake of arguing? The question asks "Is there actually a correct answer to how to pronounce foreign names when speaking English?" The correct way is obviously "the way the holder pronounces it". The question then concedes that Van Gogh is pronounced in various ways: Neither "Van Gok" nor "Van Go" are correct. /vɑŋ‿ˈɣɔx/ is correct. I did say "Some non-English names do contain sounds (or combinations of sounds) that are difficult for people who do not speak that language, and attempts at pronunciation may be inaccurate."

@Greybeard I am not arguing for the sake of arguing. I have been explaining why this answer's basic premise is wrong, in the spirit of constructive criticism. If anyone is arguing for the sake of arguing, it is the person who offered the points "you are wrong" and "it does" without elaboration, discussion, or explanation.

Furthermore, I've never heard "Van Gok"; the prevailing pronunciation other than "Van Go" is "Van Goff."  And my point relative to that is that there is a standard pronunciation in the UK and a different standard pronunciation in the US, both "inaccurate" renderings of the Dutch pronunciation, but both "correct" in their own contexts, at least in one sense of "correct."
